# Adding new states to existing Windows workflow?

Tags: workflow-foundation

If I have a long running Workflow (that lasts for months....) and if I need to for example add a new state or change it. (because of a bug fix or new feature).

What happens to existing workflows? will they be lost? or do I need to some versioning? or will it accept the new state an go on?

Answer (score 0):

Provided the workflow can rehydrate correctly I'd think that it will pick up the new assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

Changes to the workflow will not affect workflows already executing.
The entire workflow is serialized to your persistence store in its current state.

If you want to modify an existing workflow, you need to actually go through a bunch of hoops to make that happen.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that persistence is configured, in progress workflows will not be lost - they stay in the instance store waiting to resume, but in general, most of what I've read by people with good reputations (Ron Jacobs/Maurice) and others say that nearly ALL changes to existing workflows are capable of breaking in progress workflows. I've personally not made a change yet that hasn't broken mine (but I am not an expert by any means), so determining if you need to manage different versions of workflow processes is something you will need to deal with as early as possible in your planning.

You will need to determine early on what happens in the case of bug fixes and/or new features, and then decide whether or not in progress workflows will be allowed to finish with the current definition, or whether they will need to be terminated and re-run with the new definition.

If you must terminate and re-run, then you won't necessarily need to deal with workflow versioning, but you will need to deal with any "artifacts" of the in progress workflow - delete them? do your own "update" on them?

If you can let in play workflows finish, and only have newly started processes use the updated workflow, you will need to deal with versioning of the workflows. This is what I am facing currently, and while the concepts are not especially difficult (WCF routing), I'm finding the implementation details daunting.